# Where is the structure for payload of netlink message defined for NETLINK_XFRM socket

Tags: sockets, netlink, ipsec

I am running strongswan daemon to perform IKEv2 messaging.

I wrote some python code to be notified everytime any xfrm change happens.

The socket is created like so:

```
my_socket = socket.socket(socketAF_NETLINK, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.NETLINK_XFRM)
```

I receive and decode the `nlmsghdr` structure defined in `./uapi/linux/netlink.h` like so:

```
while True:
  data = my_socket.recv(65535)
  msg_len, msg_type, flags, seq, pid = struct.unpack("=LHHLL", data[:16])
  print msg_type
```

This works fine, I get the message type every time an new SA is made or updated or deleted.

Now, I attempt to decode the payload of this message, but I cannot locate the structure in linux to decode it with.

There is a file called `uapi/linux/xfrm.h` but I am not sure if this file contains the payload structure.

Can someone share where the payload structure is defined for xfrm netlink messages?

Comment: netlink is not well documented. Look at how the `iproute2` (`ip` program) does it. Or look at the kernel code that sends the messages.

Answer (score 0):

*uapi/linux/xfrm.h* is indeed the file you needed. `struct xfrm_usersa_info` is the struct you're looking for